# Running an external program like hdiutil from an .app folder on Mac OS X

Tags: java, macos, dmg

I made a .app folder containing a Java application and a JRE. I used app-bundle-maven plugin to create the .app folder.

My Java application creates a .dmg file from an ISO image and does this by starting hdiutil as subprocess.

This works without any problems when running from the command line or the IDE but fails when started from the .app folder.

The ProcessBuilder throws an IOException that /usr/bin/hdiutil is not found.

My questions are: Is the .app folder like a sandbox ?
Is there a setting in the Info.plist file that is able to override the sandbox behavior ?

Info.plist:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
  <dict>
    <key>CFBundleDevelopmentRegion</key>
    <string>English</string>
    <key>CFBundleExecutable</key>
    <string>JavaAppLauncher</string>
    <key>CFBundleIconFile</key>
    <string>usbboot.icns</string>
    <key>CFBundleIdentifier</key>
    <string>de.bamamoto.mactools.usbboot.USBBoot</string>
    <key>CFBundleDisplayName</key>
    <string>USBBoot</string>
    <key>CFBundleInfoDictionaryVersion</key>
    <string>6.0</string>
    <key>CFBundleName</key>
    <string>USBBoot</string>
    <key>CFBundlePackageType</key>
    <string>APPL</string>
    <key>CFBundleShortVersionString</key>
    <string>1.0-SNAPSHOT</string>
    <key>CFBundleSignature</key>
    <string>????</string>
    <key>CFBundleVersion</key>
    <string>1</string>
    <key>NSHumanReadableCopyright</key>
    <string></string>
    <key>NSHighResolutionCapable</key>
    <true/>
    <key>JVMRuntime</key>
    <string>JRE</string>
    <key>JVMMainClassName</key>
    <string>de.bamamoto.mactools.usbboot.USBBoot</string>
    <key>JVMClassPaths</key>
    <array>
      <string>de/bamamoto/webmusic/USBBoot/1.0-SNAPSHOT/USBBoot-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar</string>
    </array>
    <key>JVMVersion</key>
    <string>1.6+</string>
    <key>JVMOptions</key>
    <array>
       <string>-Dapple.laf.useScreenMenuBar=true</string>
      <string>-Xdock:name=USBBoot</string>
      <string>-Djava.util.Arrays.useLegacyMergeSort=true</string>
    </array>
    <key>JVMArguments</key>
    <array/>
    <key>LauncherWorkingDirectory</key>
    <string>$APP_ROOT</string>
  </dict>
</plist>
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution for this problem. A file called jspawnhelper located in the JREs lib folder has lost his execute flag during the copy operation. This file is needed when using ProcessBuilder.start() or Runtime.exec() method calls.

The thrown IOException that the executable was not found was misleading.
After setting the execute flag on this file everything works as expected.